# Correct JSON Parsing without substringBetween

Tags: apex, json, parser

I'm using a bad practice in my code. I get all needed values from JSON like this:

```
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('Endpoint is here');
    request.setMethod('GET'); 
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
    List<Object> received = (List<Object>) results.get('tools');
    List<Obj__c> newCardsList = new List<Obj__c>();

    for(Object each : received){
        String inText = String.valueOf(each);
        String name = inText.substringBetween('), name=', '}');
        String cardId = inText.substringBetween('id=', ',');
        //The biggest trouble:
        String dueDateInText = inText.substringBetween('due=', 'T');
        Date dueDate;
        if(dueDateInText != null){
            dueDate = Date.valueOf(dueDateInText);
        }
    }
```

How do i do it right? Especially with the date: the required value is between `due=` and `T`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `deserializeUntyped()`, you get an `Object` back, which is usually either cast to `Map<String, Object>` or `List<Object>`.

The thing that you're missing here is that each object that you get from your Map or List can also be cast.

Applying this to your loop, we get

```
for(Object each : received){
    Map<String, Object> nextLevel = (Map<String,Object>)each;

    String name = (String)nextLevel.get('name');
    Date dueDate = (Date)nextLevel.get('due');
}
```

Of course, if you don't want to bother with casting everything all the time, you could create an Apex class that mimics your JSON structure and use `JSON.deserialize(jsonStr, MyDeserializationClass.class);`

Comment: Thank you so much! And what if we have `{labels=({due=null, name=}), name=Name}`? I can't get `due` like that.

Comment: @MichaelLev19 Yes you can. Just apply the same pattern until you get to your desired level. Like I said in my answer, _each object you get from your Map or List can also be cast_. Expanding on that a bit, each JSON object can be cast to a `Map<String, Object>`, each JSON list can be cast to a `List<Object>`, and individual values (name, due, id, etc...) can be cast to more concrete types (String, Date, etc...). I'd encourage you to play around with this yourself for a while via anonymous apex. You'll likely find it easier to internalize this if you figure out the exact code to use yourself.

Comment: @MichaelLev19 I also hope that it's becoming clear why making a class to do _typed_ deserialization is an attractive option. Sure, you can use loops and type-cast everything, but making a class to deserialize this saves you the trouble. You'd be able to access your data using more familiar means, something like `Date dueDate = deserialized.tools[0].labels.due;` for example (though encountering a collection is a pretty strong indicator that you'll want to loop over it instead of accessing a single index).

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to get the date/datetim, you can try the following code:

```
String s = '2019-07-09T09:27:29Z';
s = s.replace('T', ' ').replace('Z', '');
Datetime theDatetime = Datetime.valueOf(s);
// or if you just want to get a date format
Date theDate = theDatetime.date();
```

Comment: No, I need only date :) Can I take the values from JSON another way? I really think it's a little silly of me to do this through `substring`.